# Laravel - PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'vestibulare.app\models\telefone' doesn't exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, php-7

I'm new to Laravel.

I'm trying to access some data from within a partial view.

I tried to put my query inside the `boot` method of `AppServiceProvider`, but Im getting this error:

```
PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'vestibulare.app\models\telefone' doesn't exist")
```

I can't even run `php artisan serve`.

Why is Laravel assuming my model's name is in the singular?

Here are my models:

```
class Usuario extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'usuarios';
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = [
        'nome'
    ];

    public function telefones()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Telefone::class, 'id_usuario');
    }
}
```

```
class Telefone extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'telefones';
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $casts = [
        'id_usuario' => 'int'
    ];

    protected $fillable = [
        'id_usuario',
        'numero'
    ];

    public function usuario()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Usuario::class, 'id_usuario');
    }
}
```

Here's the `boot` method inside `app\Providers\AppServiceProvider` class:

```
public function boot()
    {
        $data = Usuario::join(Telefone::class, "usuarios.id", "=", "telefones.id_usuario")
            ->select(
                "usuarios.id as u.id",
                "usuarios.nome as nome",
                "telefones.numero as numero",
                DB::raw("COUNT(numero) AS numero_count")
            )
            ->groupBy("nome")
            ->orderBy("nome")
            ->get();

        view()->with(["data" => $data]);
    }
```

Initially, the query inside `boot` method was inside my controller's `index` method, like so:

```
class ContactListController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        // $usuarios = Usuario::all();
        // $telefones = Telefone::all();
        $data = Usuario::join(Telefone::class, "usuarios.id", "=", "telefones.id_usuario")
            ->select(
                "usuarios.id as u.id",
                "usuarios.nome as nome",
                "telefones.numero as numero",
                DB::raw("COUNT(numero) AS numero_count")
            )
            ->groupBy("nome")
            ->orderBy("nome")
            ->get();

        return view("index", compact("data"));
    }
    {...}
}
```

Why am I getting this error?

How can I access the data I want from within the partial data?

Here are my views:

**index.blade.php**

```
<html>
@include("header")
@include("search_contact")
@include("contact_list")
@include("footer")
</html>
```

**contact_list.blade.php** <- I want to access data from here

```
<div class="col-lg-8">

    <table id="myTable" class="table text-justify table-striped">
        <thead class="tableh1">
            <th class="">Name</th>
            <th class="col-3">Nº of Phones</th>
            <th class="">Phone</th>
        </thead>

        <tbody id="tableBody">

            @foreach ($data as $item)
            <tr>
                <!-- Test -->
                <td>{{ $item }}</td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach

        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I've been reading the docs, watching tutorials and searching for similar questions for over 6 hours. Please help me.

Thank you in advance.

---

Edit:

I've tried changing the query to the following:

```
$data = Usuario::join("telefones", "usuarios.id", "=", "telefones.id_usuario")
            ->select(
                "usuarios.id as u.id",
                "usuarios.nome as nome",
                "telefones.numero as numero",
                DB::raw("COUNT(telefones.numero) AS numero_count")
            )
            ->groupBy("nome")
            ->orderBy("nome")
            ->get();
```

Where insteaad of using `Telefone::class` I'm now using `telefones`. I got a different error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'vestibulare.usuarios.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by (SQL: select `usuarios`.`id` as `u.id`, `usuarios`.`nome` as `nome`, `telefones`.`numero` as `numero`, COUNT(telefones.numero) AS numero_count from `usuarios` inner join `telefones` on `usuarios`.`id` = `telefones`.`id_usuario` group by `nome` order by `nome` asc)
```

---

Edit 2:

I've changed the following line inside my `database.php` config file:

```
'mysql' => [
    ...
    'strict' => true,
    ...
]
```

To:

```
'mysql' => [
    ...
    'strict' => false,
    ...
]
```

Now I'm not getting the above error anymore, but there's something wrong with my query because it's coming back empty.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can use the class name within the join. You might need to specify the table outright. `Usuario::join('telefones',... `

Comment: I tried your suggestion and got a different error. I've updated the question to include it.

Comment: @aynber You were right. Doing the above solved it. The reason I wasn't getting anything from my query was because I forgot I had to drop the tables and so they were empty. Should I post your solution or will you?

Comment: It looks like Ilkhomjon, so go ahead and accept that one.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe do you try with DB?

```
\DB::table('usuarios')->join('telefones', ....
```

Comment: I've updated the question after trying what you said. I'm now getting an empty result.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I will do

```
class Usuario extends Model { 
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $table = 'usuarios';    

    protected $with=['telefonos'];

    protected $fillable = [
        'nome'
    ];

    public function telefones()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Telefone::class);
    }
}


class Telefone extends Model {
    protected $table = 'telefones';
    public $timestamps = false;


    protected $fillable = [
        'id_usuario',
        'numero'
    ];

    public function usuario()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Usuario::class);
    }
}

//Here's the boot method inside app\Providers\AppServiceProvider class:

// do not use this for querys to database
    public function boot()
    {
        
    }

class ContactListController extends Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $usuarios = Usuario::all();
        return view("index", $usuarios);
    }
    {...}
}

// And your view 

<div class="col-lg-8">

    <table id="myTable" class="table text-justify table-striped">
        <thead class="tableh1">
            <th class="">Name</th>
            <th class="col-3">Nº of Phones</th>
            <th class="">Phone</th>
        </thead>

        <tbody id="tableBody">

            @foreach ($usuarios as $usuario)
            <tr>
                @php

                $telefono = $usuario->tefono ?? 'This user has no telephone';
                
                @endphp

                <td>Nome: {{$usuario->nome}} Telef: {{$telefono}} </td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach

        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

And finally return mysql values to original state.